# Change layer of multiple objects

Tags: layers

For some reason the cell fracture addon put all the shards (about 50 of them) to be on all the layers, instead of keeping them on the first layer. I use these layers for other things, so leaving them isn't an option. How do I set all of the shards to be in the first layer, without having to do all of them by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select them all. Without knowing the layout of your scene, it's hard to say what the best way to do this is.

   - Manual:

     Try pressing <kbd>`</kbd> (the key below <kbd>Esc</kbd>, at least on qwerty keyboards) to set all layers visible. Then use Border select (<kbd>B</kbd>) or circle select (<kbd>C</kbd>) in wireframe mode to select all the shards (you may also want to try hiding (<kbd>H</kbd>) any other objects which are in the way, or just deselect them afterwards)
   - Automated:

     If the shards have anything in common, you could try using *Select similar* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>). For example, this can be used to select them if they are all part of the same group (rigid bodies are automatically part of a group called rigid body world, so that might help if they are rigid bodies).
     Or *Select Linked* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>). This will select objects sharing a datablock such as a material or a texture (so you could use this if the shards all have the same texture).

     Note that <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> only select visible objects, so you may want to set all layers visible first (<kbd>`</kbd>).
2. Press <kbd>M</kbd> and click the layer which you want the shards to be on (you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to select multiple layers).